# Assert that two object's keys overlap

Tags: typescript

I have these two object types:

```
const main = {
  a: {name: "A"},
  b: {name: "The B"},
  c: {name: "The Sea"},
  // ...
} as const;

export interface Subset {
  b?: string,
  c?: string[],
}
```

I want to make sure that `Subset` only has keys that are also on `main` at the type level and I don't accidentally define `Subset.uniqueKey` for example. How do I do that?

What if there's just a few not shared keys that I want to explicitly list as exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a utility to make sure a type satisfies the bounds of another,

```
type Satisfies<T, U extends T> = void;
```

we can then assert that the keys of `Subset` are a subset of the keys in `main`:

```
type AssertSubsetKeys = Satisfies<keyof typeof main, keyof Subset>;
```

and when you have an extra key (say, "d"), TypeScript will provide a helpful error:

> Type 'keyof Subset' does not satisfy the constraint '"a" | "b" | "c"'.
> Type '"d"' is not assignable to type '"a" | "b" | "c"'.(2344)

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwJZhgXhgbwLACgYwIBcWYCcApiQEQCC1AvgDR4EBGJmZlNAKgBYUYAIUYt8MYJ25UY1AUIDKFBGNYwA9BpgA6PXgaEIk8NADcePFACeAByUIoSCADMkFCAB5eTGAFUYCgAPKAowABNjXgA+dBgANxAkcItcPGDbEAAnWBRQrJcEYCUAVzYIClgcCTYAfhJoLJQAc3ECYHqYRpaAbQBdPC0CcJIwErg2CizNbRKwUDhKMFgofmcYABsUISgQLoohBFQprOyDS1wbexhaCAqcxTKKqABpCmtjDEVHZzcPTwA1u8QC4YFcKCD4MgwL4gdZIY9ypVomYgA)